# Mask URL into a shorter one

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, url, mask

I have a project where I need to mask the url.

Before: example.com/pogi/ako/
After: example.com/ako/

The application is created using codeigniter. Thoug the one found on the sub-directory have another webservice created with codeigniter as well. I tried doing some configurations I know with .htaccess and httpd.conf, but I was not able to make it run.

Comment: I think you might be confusing URL shortening with URL rewriting.

Comment: I might be confused... What I need is URL Shortening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to remember how Codeigniter Handles URLs, you mentiond **Sub Directory** in your Question which also is Codeigniter Based **Web Service** !

When you are Running **first** Codeigniter App it will Catch your requested Url and get the **related** Controller and it's Method to Handle it !

Your Controllers can be nested in **Sub Directory** too ! also as @Ross Mentioned in his answer, this behavior can be override using [Routes](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=routes) !

Answer (score 1):

In the file "application/config/routes.php" add the line:

```
$route['ako'] = 'pogi/ako';
```

This will make is so that any request that comes through to `example.com/ako` will actually go to `example.com/pogi/ako` but it won't look like that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The subdirectory is another CI based web application, I tried using routes but it doesn't work.

The application in example.com is different from example.com/pogi/ako